# Why is it not showing me calendar under the textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, calendar

I have copied this code from a website http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/jquery-dropdownlist-selection-for.html and its not showing me the desired output, I'm Naive at this but the calendar is not visible below the textbox which should as per the code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1970:2012'
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker { font-size:8pt !important}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="demo">
<b>Date:</b> <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up calendar by using ajax calendar extender..

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per you First statement you copied the code so check that your application contain js folder or not

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your website project includes the reference files in your project

1. css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css
2. js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
3. js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js

If not you can download the same from [jquery](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/04/jquery-ui-1-8-19/) site and include same in your project or provide http path for reference files